# when I want to access the children of parsed tree using .contents I am unable to reach the childrens but with find i can find children why?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

using .contents

```
    `url="https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/"
     import requests
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
     re=requests.get(url)
     doc=BeautifulSoup(re.content,"html.parser")
     table=doc.find('tbody',class_="lister-list")
     print(table.contents[0])`
```

using find

```
    `url="https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/"
     import requests
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
     re=requests.get(url)
     doc=BeautifulSoup(re.content,"html.parser")
     table=doc.find('tbody',class_="lister-list")
     print(table.find('tr'))`
```

the .contents is not working why

Answer (score 0):

Because `.contents` will give you *all* content of the node - that means string, tags, html comments etc.

If you do `print(table.contents)` it will print:

```py
['\n', <tr>
<td class="posterColumn">
<span data-value="1" name="rk"></span>
<span data-value="9.23450250788211" name="ir"></span>

...
```

so first item is string `\n` (and this will be printed with your script).
If you will do `print(table.contents[1])` it will give you the `<tr>` tag.